# How to change default app to open file from Office 365 OneDrive?

Tags: office365, onedrive, microsoft-onenote

I use OneDrive Office 365 in the browser and open files via desktop app. I have 2 versions of OneNote desktop app and browser opens file in a wrong version.

How do I change default desktop app to open a file in?

Thanks!

Comment: Two versions?? If they are the same app but one is simply newer than the other, any default app ref will always open the newer [in some instances if the older is already open it can signal the OS for handoff]. If they are actually distinctly different apps, then the Default Apps control panel should be able to set it.

Comment: Thanks @Tetsujin. One is regular OneNote for Windows 10, another is Office 365 for Desktop. When I opened file first time it asked me which OneNote to choose and offered 2 visually identical options. Once I select one (wrong one), I wasn't able to select another. The choice was via the browser window, so I cannot find the setting anywhere. The only place that looks remotely correct is via preferences JSON in File Association section, but there is no clear way how to edit it.

Comment: idk the structure well-enough to be able to hone that down, sorry. Hope you find someone who can help. :)

Comment: Please add more details like name and version of the operative system, the desktop apps and web browser that you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to use OneNote 2016 to open notebooks from OneDrive?

If yes, I would suggest you go to System Settings > Apps > Default Apps, find the OneNote 2016, and choose this desktop client as the defaults apps instead of OneNote for Windows 10.

[image]

Such as on Windows 11, you can open OneNote for Windows 10 and OneNote 2016 respectively, and change the software that can be changed to OneNote 2016 to it.

Comment: Thanks! Your answer is very close, but didn't work. What worked for me is to set default app per protocol. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You are Welcome ~ :)